# arm64e back compatible with arm64

Tags: ios, arm, app-store

The latests released apple devices, iPhone XS, XS max and XR where released on mid September of 2018. Those devices have a new arm64e processor compared with the predecessor arm64.

I was wondering if the only way of executing an app on any of those devices is to compile it for arm64e. My doubts come from the fact that:

- The new models where released on 21. September 2018
- The first Xcode version supporting arm64e (10.1) came out end of October.
- Xcode 10.1 was stripping the arm64e slice when uploading to the
  App Store.

So the question: Is is possible to upload an app with only arm64 arch, and deploy it on a arm64e device?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the new devices can run applications built with older Xcode versions, for the generic arm64 iOS architecture.